# How to regex match byte strings and removing punctuation besides backslashes?

Tags: python, regex

Suppose you have a string that looks like this:

```
text = "I love  so much!"

text = text.encode()
text = b"I love \xf0\x9f\xa7\xb8 so much!"
```

I want to leave the encoded bear but remove the `!` at the end. The regex I would use to match everything but the punctuation is `text = re.sub(b"[^\w\s\\]", b"", text)`

But that throws `error: unterminated character set at position 0` because the last `]` gets escaped I think. Trying the regex as `text = re.sub(b"[^\w\s\\\]", b"", text)` resolves the error, but then the regex removes the encoded bear and the `!`. `text = b"I love so much"`

I need some way of having the `\` be apart of the regex to keep the bear. So far I've tried:

```
[^\w\s\\[\w\d]{3}]
[^\w\s\\[A-Za-z0-9]{3}]
[^\\\w\s]
```

Banging my head against a wall trying to solve this.

Comment: Are you open to removing punctuation without regex? [string.punctuation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation) can help you here after converting to `bytes` using [bytes.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.translate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method does not use regex. If using regex is a must ignore this.

```py
import string

punc = string.punctuations.encode()

text = b"I love \xf0\x9f\xa7\xb8 so much!" 

clean_text = text.translate(None, punc)
```

[bytes.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.translate) returns a copy of the bytes or bytearray object where all bytes occurring in the optional argument delete are removed.
Thus `clean_text` becomes `b"I love \xf0\x9f\xa7\xb8 so much"`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use r-string for regex instead of b-string, so instead of `b'...'` use `r'...'`. Also you can't apply regex to byte-string, so you have to convert it to string first. Below is full working code with your unchanged regex:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolasktaJEwVYhSclTISe/LFUhpiLNIKbCMi2mItE8piLJQqE4XyG3NDlDUQmmtLikSAPE1Iw2stI1jIUJF6XqFZcmaRSpR8fFlMcUx8TEqusoqAMxWC1XQVFmXglE3///AA)

```
import re
text = b"I love \xf0\x9f\xa7\xb8 so much!"
text = str(text)[2:-1]
text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s\\]', '', text)
print(text)
```

Output:

```
I love \xf0\x9f\xa7\xb8 so much
```

---

You may want to use `text.encode('unicode_escape')` (which gives `b'I love \\U0001f9f8 so much!'`) instead of just `text.encode()` (which gives `b'I love \xf0\x9f\xa7\xb8 so much!'`), because it is more correct and re-usable way to represent strings as unicode-escaped rather than hex-escaped.